# Automatic capitalization when typing terminal commands

Tags: macos, terminal

Recently when I use the terminal and I type a command, I hear a click and whatever I had typed becomes capitalized. If I'm typing `ls -lrt` I'll hear a loud click and when I look at my command it has changed to `Ls -lrt`. The same with pwd or any command I type. The capital letter will work on some commands but not all. Does anyone know how to turn this off? I went to System Preferences/keyboard/text but the selection there to use automatic capitalization is not checked. I may have inadvertently done this with Better Touch Tool but I can't find anything about it in the app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It does it on a webpage to when I try to enter something.

Comment: How do I get in Safe Mode.

Comment: No, the problem doesn't appear when I'm in safe mode

Comment: It's something that's being loaded.  Look at your login items (System Prefs -> Users) and see what's being loaded.  You can disable items that look like they will cause issues.  If you post a list, we can at least hazard a guess.

Comment: I have a bunch. How would i get a list?

Comment: screenshot.  Press Shift-Cmd-4 and take a picture of the area

Comment: I was hoping there was a text-based method. i'll make the screen shots now.

Comment: Well as I was adjusting the login item screen I noticed a few items that were there and I didn't even know what they were. I removed them and restarted and the problem has gone away.  If you want to type this up as an answer I'll certainly accept it.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should write up the answer; be sure to provide the screen shot and some of the apps.  This way future readers can search/find it.  I'll upvote for sure!

Answer (score 2):

Well I found the solution with help from @Allen. I tried restarting my computer in Safe Mode. The problem with capitalization went away. Based on this result it was probably due to something I loaded onto my machine. While I was in Safe Mode I started by looking at the Startup items found in the System Preferences/User and Groups. I hadn't carefully checked the Login Items in quite a while and I found out I had many. Some of these were suspicious in that the kind of item was unknown. I show this in the images below:

[image]

[image]

I had several that fit that description. Using the minus symbol shown in the bottom left of the window I deleted the suspicious login items and rebooted my computer back to regular user mode. To my joy the auto capitalization was gone. I deduce it must have been connected to one of the login items I removed. Had I removed them one-at-a-time I might have beem able to determine which one was the culpit. As it is I can only narrow it down to the ones I removed. None of these were new additions so I must have changed settings in one of these to suddenly cause my troubles. Due either to old age or the fact that auto capitalization was driving me crazy, I can't recall what changes were made recently. I may go back and try to determine which specific one was causing this but that is left for a future date.